# Laravel 5.1: confused by the way namespaces and facades work within PHPUnit Test classes extending TestCase

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, phpunit, laravel-facade

I'm creating base test class from which other test classes can extend from and be ran with PHPUnit. This base test class extends Laravel's provided `TestCase` class. Also, I'm using the [PHP Faker library](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker) to create a faker generator and as, well, I'm calling on Laravel's Artisan facade to run a database migration in the `setUp` method. . Here's what it looked like initially:

```
<?php
// BaseTester.php

use Artisan;
use Faker\Factory as Faker;

class BaseTester extends TestCase {

  protected $fake;

  function __construct() {
    $this->fake = Faker::create();
  }

  public function setUp()
  {
    parent::setUp();

    Artisan::call('migrate', [
      '--seed' => true,
    ]);
  }
}
```

When I ran PHPUnit the first time, it succeeded but also gave this warning:

`PHP Warning:  The use statement with non-compound name 'Artisan' has no effect in /Users/myusername/Sites/app/tests/BaseTester.php on line 3`

Ok so then I wondered why it would give me that. So I tried removing:

`use Artisan;`

from the `BaseTester.php` class and it worked, all tests passed, and also no warning in the output.

Now, I wondered why I had to remove that `use` statement. Then I remembered that on my `config/app.php` file that there's an alias available for the `Artisan` facade.

```
...

'aliases' => [

        'App'       => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
        'Artisan'   => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
        'Auth'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
...
```

So then it must get loaded automatically. Which means, if there's also an Alias for the Faker facade within the `config/app.php` file

```
...
/*
 * Third party libraries / packages aliases
 */
'Faker'     => Faker\Factory::class,
...
```

then it also must get loaded so I don't have to include:

`use Faker\Factory as Faker;`

in my `BaseTester.php` file and I can just call the `Faker::create` method within it.

so I removed that `use` statement as well and ran PHPUnit but then I got this error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Faker' not found in /Users/myusername/Sites/app/tests/BaseTester.php on line 12`

So now I'm really confused because the call to `Artisan` which is included in the `config/app.php` file under the aliases section works but not the call to `Faker` which is also included in that same file under the same aliases section.

In the end, my code looks like this,

```
<?php
// BaseTester.php

use Faker\Factory as Faker;

class BaseTester extends TestCase {

  protected $fake;

  function __construct() {
    $this->fake = Faker::create();
  }

  public function setUp()
  {
    parent::setUp();

    Artisan::call('migrate', [
      '--seed' => true,
    ]);
  }
}
```

and it works without warnings, but I don't understand what's going in terms of aliases and namespaces and facades and I feel that until I get a handle on this then I don't truly understand how Laravel does its thing.

I just end up trying to find the right combination of `use` statements with Laravel facades within other code files until I get no errors.